# Right sequence of events with simple classification (Naive Bayes and Decision Tree)

Tags: classification, cross-validation, naive-bayes, confusion-matrix

I'm implementing Naive Bayes and a Decision Tree on the same data, and I need to cross validate with Kfold.

Do I have the right sequence of events? Overall, does it make sense or am I misunderstanding something? Some of what I've read is contradictory.

1. Train_test_split (75/25 or whatever)
2. Fit the model with X, y Training data
3. Predict the model with X Test data
4. cross_val_score using K(5)fold validation using Training data (and not the whole dataset) to see how good the model can fit.
5. Confusion matrix on y_test, y_pred (y_pred is output from #3)
6. Classification report on y_test, y_pred (y_pred is output from #3)
7. Display the model with training data and display it again with test data to visualize the two results.

Comment: This seems to short for an answer, but since there is not much else to say: Yes, this seems about right. Perhaps there would be more to say if you could elaborate what you have read that was contradictory.

Comment: I've seen people apply kfold validation to the whole dataset, instead of just the training portion.

Comment: That would be wrong, because you then don't have an independent dataset anymore for reporting the prediction accuracy